# Verilog: Adding individual bits of a register (combinational logic, register width is parameterizable)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to come up with a way to add individual bits of a register. 
eg, `if regA = 111000 then regB = 3` (Sum of bits of `regA`).
1) Is there any synthesizable function/operator in Verilog or SystemVerilog which I can directly use to do this operation?

If not, then maybe the problem is a little interesting, especially because the operation has to be done in one clock cycle (pure combinational logic) and the register width is parameterizable.

2) In case there is no inbuilt Verilog or SystemVerilog operator then what can be done?

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verilog (IEEE Std 1364-2001 or newer):

```
integer i;
always @* begin
  B = WIDTH_LOG2'b0;
  for (i=0; i<WIDTH; i=i+1)
    B = B + A[i];
end
```

SystemVerilog (IEEE Std 1800-2005 or newer):

```
always_comb begin
  B = '0; // fill 0
  foreach(A[i])
    B += A[i];
end
```

Both will synthesize to combination logic. No latches or flops.

SystemVerilog does have `$countones()`, but I'm unsure if it is synthesizable. Ff it is then: `always_comb B = $countones(A)`

Comment: Hi @Greg, 

Thanks for your reply. I tried to run a test code in both Xilinx ISE and Altera Quartus synthesis tool, I am not getting a pure combinational circuit ([Synthesized RTL schematic from Quartus2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2GvkmOyTwO5Z0FvYUZJa2czdEU/edit?usp=sharing)). This is the code I used:

`module test( A, C);
  parameter A_WIDTH = 8;
  parameter C_WIDTH = 3;
input [A_WIDTH-1:0] A;
output reg [C_WIDTH-1:0] C;
integer i;

always @ * begin
C<=3'd0;
for (i = 0; i<A_WIDTH;i=i+1)
begin
C <= C + A[i];
end
end

endmodule`

Not sure if it is readable, please let me know if so.

Comment: Solved! I was making a mistake between blocking and nonblocking assignment.

Comment: @Ujjwal, correct, blocking is for combination logic and non-blocking is for flops and latches. One benefit of SystemVerilog is `always_comb` must be combination across all tools (simulator,synthesizer, linter, RTL vs. gate comparator, etc).

Comment: I usually write Verilog code (feeling stupid right now, since its not usual for me to make an "assignment" mistake). This is the first time I am venturing into the world of SV (realizing its power). Thanks for taking out time to reply to the question!

Comment: It's not a mistake to use NBAs in combinatorial logic; the only potential downside is that it may take slightly longer to simulate. An NBA doesn't turn something from 'combinatorial' to 'sequential'. `always_comb` fixes an initialisation problem with Verilog's `always` - it looks a lot more like a VHDL process.

Comment: @EML It is a mistake in this instance. Run the non-blocking with a test bench and notice `C` will stay the same if `A[A_WIDTH-1]==0` and increment on `@(A)`and `A[A_WIDTH-1]==1`. Blocking will give the correct result in the same test bench. Best practice is blocking for combination logic, non-blocking for synchronous logic.

Comment: The error in Ujjwal's code is that he has a zero-delay loop, and he was assuming that he could read the new value of `C` after assigning to it with an NBA. This has got nothing to do with whether or not his process is combinatorial or sequential; he would have exactly the same error if his process was clocked, because it contains a zero-delay loop. In other words, if he had @(posedge clk) instead of @*, it would make no difference. I agree that it's good style to use blocking assignments in combinatorial processes, but it is only style - it's not a mistake not to.

Comment: The IEEE Std 1364-2001 version written here is actually mostly SV, not Verilog, but I get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. I am not exactly sure what it will synthesize to but it should work.

```
int i; 
reg [`WIDTH-1:0]    A;
reg [`WIDTH_LOG2:0] B;

B = 0;

for(i = 0; i < `WIDTH; i = i + 1)
begin
   B = B + A[i];
 end
```

Of course there are more complex ways that may have better performance, depending on on your tool flow and what is available, where you can create your own adders and cascade them in parallel reducing the size each step. Assuming the width was 32-bits, something like:

```
 adder1bit_1(output1, A[31:24]); 
 adder1bit_2(output2, A[23:16]);
 adder1bit_3(output3, A[15:8]);
 adder1bit_4(output4, A[7:0]);

 adder3bit_1(output5, output1, output2);
 adder3bit_2(output6, output3, output4);

 adder4bit(final_ouput, output5, output6);
```

Comment: I think that should synthesize, just make sure you put it inside an `always @(A)` block (and you have to initialize B to zero before the loop).

Comment: Thanks Josh and Tim for the replies.
@Josh Here is the catch, if I use a for loop then during synthesis it is inferred as a flip-flop. So basically I will be using a number of flipflops which would pipeline all the B=B+A[i] adders. So this approach can't be implemented.

Comment: Using individual adders is too tedious and not scalable. I can use generate statement and a for loop with that, which would essentially duplicate the hardware mentioned inside the for loop statement, but I am sure someone may have done this in a better way.

Comment: Is it actually creating flip-flops or latches? I could see it generating unintentional latches but unless the tools have some kind of special setup I don't know why it would generate flip-flops.

Comment: @Josh, Yes you are right, my bad. Since it is level triggered, and not clock edge triggered it has to be latch and not a FlipFlop(FF), sorry about that. Using latches is not a good idea for me since I am working on FPGAs, each logic block has a FF. Plus its easier to match timing in FF.

Comment: As @Tim said, it could create unintentional latches if you did not initialize the value to zero. When you tried the for loop did you have a "B=0" statement before the loop?

Comment: @Josh: `module test( A, C);
  parameter A_WIDTH = 8;
  parameter C_WIDTH = 3;
input [A_WIDTH-1:0] A;
output reg [C_WIDTH-1:0] C = 0;
integer i;

always @ * begin 
for (i = 0; i<A_WIDTH;i=i+1)
begin
C <= C + A[i];
end
end

endmodule `

This is code I wrote and synthesized just now. I am getting latches after synthesis.

Comment: Well if you use non-blocking assignment "<=" generally it is going to create latches or flip-flops. Is there a reason you use it? Using regular assignment "=" should be fine unless there is something else you are going for.

Comment: Ah! Never thought I would make this mistake. Thanks a lot Josh!!
It gets synthesized fine..